# "Под()шафе"

Tags: орфография

Что-то озадачился: "под()шафе" пишется раздельно или слитно. Просится написать раздельно по аналогии "под мухой", но подозреваю, что тут не тот случай)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подшофе. Слитно и с О.

Comment: Интересно, что у этого слова насчитывается почти 40 синонимов (Тришин В.Н. Словарь синонимов ASIS). Вот уж где народ поупражнялся вволю!

Answer (score 0):

"Под мухой" - это существительное с предлогом, а "подшофе" - это неизменяемое прилагательное, где "под-" - приставка.
В викисловаре написано, что также пишется: подшефе или устар. под-шефе

Comment: Не читайте викисловарь.

Comment: Читайте всё подряд, всё на пользу.  Почему г-н  @behemothus знает, что Викисловарь не стоит читать? Только потому, что сам читал - много и страстно...

Comment: Потому, что с таким же успехом можно читать телефонную книгу.